# Should I publish my source code as Open Source if I don't change the code

Tags: open-source, licensing, codec

I developed an application which relies on some Open Source codecs. The codecs resides in an external library. Should I publish my code if I'll not change the Open Source codec code but simple use it ? Can I use my app for commercial purposes?

Comment: it depends on the license the lib has

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on the License of the codecs and how you link the library with your Application.

It will be nice if you read more about open source licenses, If the license compels you to publish your code under the license in which the codec is published, then you will have to give your code under open source license and publish it.

But that doesn't mean that you can't use your app for commercial purposes

1. [Can I sell closed source software that depends on an open source application?](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CFQQFjAB&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1004664/can-i-sell-closed-source-software-that-depends-on-an-open-source-application&ei=H44jUNuqEobirAfomoCIAw&usg=AFQjCNHhP-Xd0mE1TOkbk04cygNquxdPcw)
2. [How to circumvent Open Source Licenses for commercial and interoperability purposes](http://www.advogato.org/article/763.html)